# Async method with an async lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a lambda expression with an async call inside

```
public async Task UploadFile(string id)
{
    Progress<double> progress = new Progress<double>(async x =>
    {
        await Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("FTPUploadProgress", x);
    });
    await client.DownloadFileAsync(localPath, remotePath, true, FluentFTP.FtpVerify.Retry, progress);
}
```

I want to call the *async* method when progress is changed.

I'm getting the following warning:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
>   Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API call

How can I make this method asynchronous?

Should I rewrite the lambda with a `System.Action<T>` class?

Comment: `UploadFile` is marked as `async` yet there's not a single `await` in it

Comment: Why do you have the `SendAsync` call inside the progress delegate? You should move that into the outer method. Then if you want to use the progress, you should pass it into a method that accepts a `Progress` parameter and implement the progress logic in the lambda expression.

Comment: I would have expected an IProgress argument passed to SendAsync ... similar as you would a CancellationToken.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I want to call the method when progress is changed...

Comment: @myro _"when progress is changed"_ The progress of what exactly?

Comment: _"I want to call the method when progress is changed"_ You should add this to your question. That's a whole different game.

Comment: use an event handler and raise it in the progress action. the event handler will allow async calls.

Comment: @Nkosi please post it as an answer, and I'll accept it

Comment: @Fildor I have added the line where the progress is used as a paramter, but now the method already is async. The question is why the method wasn't async without the line...

Comment: @myro **Because there was no `await` operator** as the warning states. An `async` method needs to have an `await` operator, otherwise, it's not asynchronous. The one you had inside the progress delegate does _not_ belong to it.

Comment: @myro That constructor of Progress is the source of your confusion. The callback was asnyc, yes. But it is not "part" of the `UploadFile` method. You could have defined it as an action somewhere else. So, although it _contained_ the word "await" - The UploadFile Method did not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an event handler and raise it in the progress action. the event handler will allow async calls.

Luckily `Progress<T>` has a `ProgressChanged` event that you can subscribe to.

Review the following example based on the presented code in original problem

```
public async Task UploadFile(string id) {
    EventHandler<double> handler = null;
    //creating the handler inline for compactness
    handler = async (sender, value) => {
        //send message to client asynchronously
        await Clients.Client(id).SendAsync("FTPUploadProgress", value);
    };
    var progress = new Progress<double>();
    progress.ProgressChanged += handler;//subscribe to ProgressChanged event

    //use the progress as you normally would
    await client.DownloadFileAsync(localPath, remotePath, true, FluentFTP.FtpVerify.Retry, progress);

    //unsubscribe when done 
    progress.ProgressChanged -= handler;
}
```

So now when progress is reported, the event handler can make the asynchronous call.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Another option would be to create you own `IProgress<T>` implementation that takes a `Func<Task<T>>` that would allow for async calls, but that might be overkill.

Comment: Seems a little bit convoluted to me. Is there a reason not to use the CTOR that takes an Action directly?

Comment: @Fildor the action will be an `async void` which is usually not advised. Event handlers are the only exception to that rule about `async void`. Check linked article in answer.

Comment: AH, now I see. I totally missed the `void`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missunderstood the usage of the `Progress<T>` class. The Compiler complains, that your Method `UploadFile` lacks an `await` operator. Your lambda *would* execute asynchronous, when it *would* be called.

So heres a short Summary how to use the `IProgressyT>` interface:

If you have a Method that should support reporting of Progress, it can take an `IProgress<T>` as an Parameter and communicate its porgress through this object. It *does not* perform the monitored Operation. The Lambda you supply is executed each time the `Report()` Method is called on the `Progress<T>`. This Lambda usually is used to update the UI.

Here is an example for that.

```
public async Task DoStuff(IProgress<double> progress = null)
{
     for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
     {
         await Task.Delay(500);
         progress?.Report((double)(i +1) / 100);
     }
}


// somewhere else in your code
public void StartProgress(){
    var progress = new Progress(p => Console.WriteLine($"Progress {p}"));
    DoStuff(progress);  
}
```

Comment: Microsoft actually recommends `progress?.Report((double)(i +1) / 100);` (treat progress so that it can be null)

Comment: @Fildor I'm surprised i forgot the '?.' here. I'll change the answer.